# How to validate boolean querys with a space in a word using the Eldar Python Package?

Tags: python

I am using the Eldar (https://github.com/kerighan/eldar) package to validate pieces of text with a boolean search string. Doing this, I also want to validate word combinations. For example, this is an example (I deliberately use match_word=True, I would like that the solution to my problem also includes this):

```
eldar = Query('("fiscale economie")', ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=True, match_word=True)
print(eldar("fiscale economie"))
```

The result of this is False, because Eldar doesn't seem to recognise the "space" that is between "fiscale" and "economie". Is there a way that Eldar can validate even word combinations, while match_word remains True?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` operator in a query. The downside of the method is that the query will match `fiscale` and `economie` whatever positions they take in the string. All documents match the query in the example below:

```py
from eldar import Query

documents = [
    "economie fiscale",
    "fiscale something economie",
    "economie something fiscale",
    "some fiscale economie thing",
    "fiscale economie"
]

eldar = Query('"fiscale" AND "economie"', ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=True, match_word=True)
print(eldar.filter(documents))
```

Unfortunately, a wildcard won't work here due to [it's implementation](https://github.com/kerighan/eldar/blob/de1c25412d563412623bd0ae5f24b507ef881e80/eldar/regex.py#L2).

Another way is to create `Index`. Searching by `economie fiscale` returns the last two documents as expected:

```py
from eldar import Index

documents = [
    "economie fiscale",
    "fiscale something economie",
    "economie something fiscale",
    "some fiscale economie thing",
    "fiscale economie"
]

index = Index(ignore_case=True, ignore_accent=True)
index.build(documents)

index.save("index.p")
index = Index.load("index.p")

print(index.search('fiscale economie'))
```